# Right click to open a terminal in Kubuntu?

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, kde

On work, I am using fedora, where a right click on desktop opens a menu, which allows opening a terminal.

Home, I have kubuntu installed. Is it possible to have the same behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"...fedora, where a right click on desktop opens a menu, which allows opening a terminal.."

**Mouse Actions**

Right click the KDE plasma desktop > Desktop settings > Mouse Actions

[image]

Application launcher has all applications.

[image]

A better version: http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Favorites+Launcher?content=117639

Description:

This is a "containment action" (mouse action) plugin for the KDE Plasma Desktop (KDE SC 4.4 or newer).

With this plugin, you can configure a mouse button click to invoke a menu with your favorite applications.

Instead of listing all applications, it only lists the Kickoff favorite applications.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Dolphin (the default KDE file manager) already include this option.

> Right click in the folder and choose Action > Open Terminal Here

The shortcut for this operation is `Shift + F4`

Comment: For that, you need to open the dolphin :) Clicking on the desktop is easier.

Comment: I logged in just to give you +1.  No need for mouse click any more

Answer (score 5):

nautilus-open-terminal will drag all the gnome + nautilus dependencies and will mess Kubuntu.

In Kubuntu if I recall, you just right click the folder you want terminal access and then choose "Open in terminal"

Comment: doh any other trick that would work for kubuntu?